# The photo doesn't center, is too big and rorated 180°

Tags: floats

The code:

```
\section{Experiment Photo}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Here is the experiment photo.
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.05]{photo.png}\\
    \caption{Experiment photo}
  \end{figure}
\end{itemize}
```

There's only one photo(500x500pt) which has the problem like this, **the other photos don't.** 
This is the result:
[image]

And this is the photo inserted. Only the left lower corner is shown..
[image]

Comment: It might be unrelated to the issue itself, but please remove the `\\ ` right before the `\caption`.

Comment: the `scale` may be the issue as I think it uses the defined DPI in the image. if the image has an strange dpi setting, the `scale` won't work as expected. Try and set the exact width or height you desire on paper using the `width` or `height` option instead of `scale`. This should at least help with the scaling issue

Comment: "Only one photo" makes me think we need access to that photo to replicate the results. Are you able to look at the bounding box for that photo?

Comment: I'm confused by (1) "This is the result" -> one low resolution picture & (2) "this is the photo inserted" -> one large no resolution picture with a decent resolution picture in the corner.  Which is your actual output?

Comment: Putting a float inside an itemized list is risky at best.  Also, I would add a blank line (or \par) at the end of the \item text, if only to make clear that the paragraph has ended.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- scale image to `\textwidth` with `width=\textwidth` (see MWE below)
- change figure placement option to `ht`
- remove `\\`  after `\includegraphics{...}` (as mentioned in @leandriis comment)
- when the image has width of text width, `\centering` is not needed

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\section{Experiment Photo}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Here is the experiment photo.
  \begin{figure}[ht] % <---
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}% <---
    \caption{Experiment photo}
  \end{figure}
  \item Other items.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```